# scale down a large image

Tags: android, bitmap

I am following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) link to load large images. So according to this link I need to fix a target height and width i.e a target resolution and image resolution should not exceed this target resolution, if it exceeds then I need to scale it down. So according to the function **calculateInSampleSize**:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
```

}

inSampleSize is calculated using half height and width. My question is why we are making computation on the basis of half height and haldf width, why not on height on width like this:

```
while ((height / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
            && (width / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I think my question has been misunderstood. I want to ask why we are not comparing reqHeight and reqWidth with full height and width of the image in above example. Why Android developer page has used halfWidth and halfImage in above example??

Comment: you can scale down your large image on the basis of width, if you are showing it in portrait mode.

Comment: @RahulSharma I think you did not get my question, I want to ask in the above example why we have not used full width and height in calculating inSampleSize ???

Comment: @RahulSharma see my edit.

Comment: oh sorry, it will cause blurring your images.

Answer (score 0):

You can find here that in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize), when sampling happens, it returns an image that is 1/2^n the width/height of the original image. So, the sampled image depends on height and width to sample it.

We works on the half of the height and width, as when we divide height and width by 2 it is like we are doing sampling by 2 and when this half of the image  is smaller than the requested height and width so we do not need to sample the original image as if we did it the sampled image will be pixeled "blurred".

Comment: ok, lets take an example, my target width and height is 300 each. Now lets suppose I have an image whose width and height is 400 each. So half will be 200 each. So calculate inSampleSize will return 1 and the image which will get loaded in memory will have resolution 400*400 which is more than the targeted one. so it is not desirable.

Comment: by default Android will scale your image down to fit the ImageView, look here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html